# First strike vs. first-strike

Tags: grammar, adjectives, hyphenation, compound-adjectives

I'm a bit confused about when to hyphenate in certain circumstances. Specifically, which of the following would I hyphenate?

> Launch a **first strike**
>
> Launch a **second strike**
>
> Damage **first strike** capabilities
>
> Damage **second strike** capabilities

I know that compound adjectives are hyphenated, but is a "first strike" a compound adjective, since it's really one concept?

Comment: How is it only a single concept? There can be many strikes only one of which can be a first strike.

Comment: Two reasons I thought it might not be hyphenated: 1) "first strikes" are (I think) a technical term for a concept in international relations literature, 2) "first strikes" are used in international relations literature (https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=%22launch+first+strikes%22&btnG=&hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C31)

Comment: https://books.google.com/books?id=OgsAAAAAMBAJ&pg=PA6&dq=First-strike+capability&hl=en&sa=X&ei=z3whVf7mKsrdsAX0_IC4Aw&ved=0CBUQ6AEwAg

Answer (score 2):

Launch a **first strike**

"first strike" here is a noun phrase --> no hyphen

Damage **first-strike capabilities**

Here, "first strike" is a compound adjective, used attributively --> hyphen

Comment: Question regarding your answer: "The capabilities damaged were first strike." Okay, that is an odd sentence, I admit, but since a verb of being separates the compound adjective from the noun it modifies, would the hyphen then disappear? Or would you have to say that the sentence is really, "The capabilities damaged were first-strike [ones]," with the pronoun *ones* omitted and implied?

Comment: Marius, it would seem wise to use full sentences as examples to make the function of the words perfectly clear.

Comment: @thb "The capabilities damaged were __first strike__." Chicago is pretty clear about this one and the reason is hyphens should be used only when one's risking ambiguity, and there's none to talk about here.